# Variable was not declared in this scope C++

Tags: c++, variables, declared-property

i'm trying to call a function in another .h file named display that receives a pointer for a `std::vector<vector<double> >` but when i try to call it i get the error that variable was not declared in this scope. Here's a sample of the code, i hope you can help.

```
//proper includes above
#include <vector>
#include "display.h"
#include "extract_balls.h"

int main(void)   
{
    std::vector<vector<double> > balls_centroids;
    std::vector<vector<double> > balls_centroids_computed;

    balls_centroids = extract_balls();

    for (vector< vector<double> >::size_type u = 0; u < balls_centroids.size(); u++) {
        vector<double> x = balls_centroids.at(u);
        x[0] = farest_point[0]-x[0];
        x[1] = farest_point[1]-x[1];
        x[2] = farest_point[2]-x[2];
        balls_centroids_computed.push_back(x);
    }

    display(&balls_centroid_computed);
}
```

The display.h file is something like this:

```
#include <vector>

void display(std::vector<std::vector<double> >& coord){

           //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Your `display()` function takes a `reference`, not a `pointer`.

Comment: Is `display()` in an alternate namespace? Or even a member function of some `class`/`struct`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare:

```
std::vector<vector<double> > balls_centroids_computed;
```

but you try to call

```
display(&balls_centroid_computed);
```

Note the difference between singular `_centroid_` and plural `_centroids_`...

Comment: I've been coding for hours, i guess my fatigue took over me. Thanks agains twalberg.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to call [...] `display()` that receives a pointer [...]

According to the prototype, `display()` takes a reference rather than a pointer.

Consequently, you don't need the ampersand in

```
    display(balls_centroid_computed);
```

Comment: Hi NPE thanks for the fast reply, i tried removing the ampersand as you said but i still get the same error.

Comment: What should be the proper way to pass the vector balls_centroid_computed so that the display function could use it?

Should i use a pointer instead of reference?

Comment: @ViriatoPT, Pass it without the ampersand. It passes the variable itself, not a copy, because of being taken by reference.

Comment: NPE thanks alot for your time and reply, my mistake re-reading the code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The display() function doesn't actually receive a pointer as you state.

If you want it to receive a pointer, declare it like:

```
void display(std::vector<std::vector<double> > * coord){

       //do stuff
```

}

The ampersand means you're passing a "reference". Suggest you only change

```
display (balls_centroid_computed)
```

Since the function is declared as a reference, you will still get most of the benefits of passing pointers (avoiding putting the whole structure onto the stack).